# Polylang and permalinks in my Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I install polylang plugin for multilanguage wordpress website and for better seo i want make diffrent permalinks . This is link for my site ;

[link to my site](http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/strona-glowna/)

What i wanna to do is Main Site url for English and Polish version look like this

> http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/

But for other subpages will be

> www.elefantti.iq.pl/%postname%

How can i achive that?

Thanks for your answers!

Update!

I try edit my htacces file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is what it look oryginaly and I add this :
RewriteRule ^$ /strona-glowna/ [L]

And it dosent work , what i do wrong?

Comment: Can you please install this plugin https://github.com/grappler/polylang-slug ?

Comment: Yes I installed this plugin , what now i need to do?

Comment: I read doc file in this plugin , there is sad that i need only instal it . But nothing happen . My domain is  www.elefantti.iq.pl , when you paste and enter you will have in Polish version www.elefantti.iq.pl/strona-glowna , and in English version www.elefantti.iq.pl/home-page  how can i cloak it